# Import HTML alt text to InDesign

Tags: html, adobe-indesign

I have HTML files with alt text in them, but when I import that HTML to InDesign, I lose the alt text.

Is there anyway to have the alt text import as well? I'd rather not have to add it all manually again :(

Comment: You may have better luck at teh [Graphic Design Stack Exchange](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/). When you do post there, I recommend you explain in detail how you import the file, what the current result is and how it differes from what you need. Posting sample data may also help

Comment: Thanks. I'll give that a shot. Thought it might be super straightforward but perhaps not.